# Deploy Blazor Webassembly on Ubuntu 20.04 server : cant connect

Tags: asp.net, linux, ubuntu, server, blazor

I'm trying to deploy my web app on Unbutu following microsoft docs :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0

When I add my app on server and run it, all look to work corectly :[image]

netstat -a -n display :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I did not forget to remove : `https://localhost:5001;` in Properties/launchSettings.json file of My BlazorApp.Server.

When I'm trying to reach "http://Myserver":5000 or 5001 , I keep getting

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Any suggestion?
I tried to modify setting to allow unsecured content on chrome.
Repeat tutorial.

EDIT :

- I tried with fresh project, same error.
- Disable all protection from chrome.
- Disable windows defender.

curl -v "ServerIp":5000 return :
`connect to "ServerIp" port 5000 failed : Connection refused`

sudo netstat -tlnp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1415/dotnet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1415/dotnet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1067/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      313/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      573/exim4
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5000                :::*                    LISTEN      1415/dotnet
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5001                :::*                    LISTEN      1415/dotnet
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      278/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      313/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      573/exim4
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not listening on the right network card.

I would try setting my application like this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#connection-logging

Comment: Or even use this method : KestrelServerOptions.ListenAnyIP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.listenanyip?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: thank you for help, seems I ddnt be able to fix this, I switched on Azure solution and It work correctly.